# Solve linear congruence: $ax + b = y \; (mod \; m)$

Tags: congruences

I am trying to solve $ax + b = y \; (mod \; m)$ for x, where $a,b,y,m$ are known values. This corresponds to running a [linear congruential generator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator) in reverse for one iteration.

I am happy to assume that $gcd(a,m) = 1$, which according to [this page](http://www.millersville.edu/~bikenaga/number-theory/linear-congruences/linear-congruences.html), means there is a single solution for $x$. I am looking for a nice algebraric manipulation of the equation that will produce this value for $x$.

I begin like this: first subtract $b$ from both sides

$$ax = y - b = u \; (mod \; m)$$

Next, compute $n$, the multiplicative inverse of $u$, to arrive at

$$axn = un = 1 \; (mod \; m)$$

How do I continue and find $x$?

Comment: Correction: There is a single solution for $x$ mod m.

Comment: You want to find the inverse of $a$, not of $u$.  For intuition, ask yourself what you would do if it were a regular equation, not a modular equation.  You would divide both sides by $a$.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Of course, I should have been "dividing" by $a$, which makes sense now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you have $ax = u \pmod{m}$, just multiply by $a$'s inverse in $\Bbb Z/m\Bbb Z$ (i.e. the only solution to $a a' = 1 \pmod{m}$ since you assume $\gcd(a,m)=1$):
$$x = a^{-1} ax = a^{-1}u \pmod{m}$$

There's a lot of info (including computation methods) on [modular inverse on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_multiplicative_inverse).